# How to check date , latitude and longitude is empty or null in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a class called `User` with this data:

```
Id = 2,
FirstName = "Arthor",
BirthDate = "12-2-1945",
BirthPlace = "Canada",
DeathDate = "1-jan-1990",
Latitude = 5.418454,
Longitude = 60.421141,
```

I want to validate these data before sending them to the front-end application. I want to validate,

1. If `BirthPlace` is NULL or empty --> here `BirthPlace` is a string type, not DateTime.
2. If `Latitude` and `Longitude` are NULL or empty --> here Lat and Long are `double` datatype.

To achieve this I have implemented the method. So I am trying to read all incoming records using for-each loop and inside that, I want to validate them and need to return only valid data.

This is my method

```
private List<User> validateUser(List<User> users)
{
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        if (user.BirthDate == null || user.BirthDate == string.Empty)
        {
        }
        else if (user.Latitude > 0 || user.Latitude == null)
        {
        } 
        else if (user.Longitude > 0 || user.Longitude == null)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure if I am following the right way or not, because I have many if-else conditions inside the fore-each loop. So someone can help me to avoid this code duplication and finally return only valid data to the end user I mean need to add parameter data to the User object and need to return. Thanks.

I have tried like this also, but I'm getting an error:

```
private List<User> User(List<User> users)
{
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        var userLists = new User
                {
                    Id = user.Id,
                    FirstName = user.FirstName,
                    LastName = user.LastName,
                    if (user.BirthDate != null)
                    {
                        BirthDate = user.BirthDate
                    }
                    Latitude = mapIndividual.Latitude,
                    Longitude = mapIndividual.Longitude,
                };
            }

    return mapIndividuals;
}
```

Errors: `BirthDay` does not exist in the current context. I think that I used if condition. And also user latitude and longitude red line is appier. Also near the all commas have read line. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You're logic above is technically correct, but there are other options as well.  Since you are using ASP.NET Core, I would recommend reading this section of the documentation regarding validation.  It applies to Web API as well as Razor Pages and MVC.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: when you have multiple users: loop the users. When you have multiple properties: loop the properties. When you have both: do both. So your approach is purely fine, there's no duplication here - however I agree Cobster there are ready-to-use solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have updated my questions. Added one more code sample here at the last. But showing some errors. do you guys have any idea about that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to validate the values entered in the objects in users list. You need to remember that lat and long can be negative numbers as well as both can be 0. Depending if they are set to be nullable they can be checked against the null values, however if they are not, they will be equal to 0.

```
 private List<User> validateUser(List<User> users)
    List<User> validUsers = new List<User>();
    {

        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.BirthDate) && user.Latitude != null && user.Longitude != null)
            {
               validUsers.add(user);
            }
       
        }
     return validUsers;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is works for me. And can you update your answer if the Lat and Long == 0 and Lat and Long is negative values how can I validate. Also need to check null. Here lat long data type is Double.  Could please help me

Comment: Also I am getting warning when I check lat long is null : the result of the expression is always true since a value of type double is never equal to null
of type double

Comment: Here if the condition is true . that mean BirthDate Lat, Long all coming. but here validUsers.add(user) is not calling if the condition is true.

Comment: Hi,@santest , have you check the document?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types